# How can i get more RAM for mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ram

I have a program in PHP, that needs to utilize the max of memory. I lunch then 50 script to get max off CPU but in RAM i have just 450 M  How i can gat my 8 Go of my RAM i have 8G in my RAM please look the Image

[image]

Please help me

I have this in my.ini

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 4000M
max_allowed_packet = 1000M
sort_buffer_size = 100M
net_buffer_length = 512K
read_buffer_size = 1000M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2000M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 5000M
basedir=D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=D:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

lc-messages-dir=D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/share

# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR

# Avoid warning
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)


# New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 1600M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 2000M
sort_buffer_size = 2000M
read_buffer = 200M
write_buffer = 200M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 2000M
sort_buffer_size = 2000M
read_buffer = 200M
write_buffer = 200M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

Comment: Why does your application need to utilise all RAM?

Comment: because i have to change sam data in my data and its for one time

Comment: I have over 30 Million From data and I want to make a change in the data integrality and I need 50 demarer script for the Serant aperture data regardless of time and not wait a long time to have the same result

Comment: Changing data does not necessarily require lot of memory, nor will more memory necessarily speed up an update.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to achive. I'm voting to close this topic for being unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql memory is handled in the configuration file. There are several settings that control memory and must be tuned based on your individual needs.

After reading the document found at the link below, you should have a good understanding of what you need to do to tune your server memory usage or, at least, know where to start a search to learn more.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-parameters.html